# how to use the output of a bash script in a Golang function

Tags: go, redirect, environment-variables, global-variables

This might not even be possible but I've been researching for the past hour and come up blank. I have a bash script that gives me a certain output and I want to add that output to Golang in order to redirect a website based on the output of the bash script. Sorry if this makes no sense, im new to Go

Here is what I have to run the bash script and output the value

```
 func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "script.sh").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf(string(out))
}
```

I then want to use the value that was output there in another function and to redirect a URL heres how I would redirect to a url and I wanted the `$variable` to be added. This is just an example I copied off the internet but its what I want to replicate.

```
func redirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    http.Redirect(w, r, "**$variable**", 301)
}
 func main() {
     http.HandleFunc("/", redirect)
     err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
     if err != nil {
         log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
     }
 }
```

Comment: At what moment is your bash script run? At startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your script must be only run once at startup, then this should do the trick:

```golang
var redirectTo string

func redirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(w, r, redirectTo, 301)
}

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "script.sh").Output()
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }
    redirectTo = string(out)
    http.HandleFunc("/", redirect)
    err = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to have a global variable you can generate the redirect function at runtime:

```golang
func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "script.sh").Output()
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.Redirect(w, r, string(out), 301)
    })
    err = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

if you want to handle when out is empty, you can do:

```golang
func redirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if len(redirectTo) == 0 {
        http.Error(w, "No URL parsed!", 500)
        return
    }
    http.Redirect(w, r, redirectTo, 301)
}
```

This will return an HTTP error 500 in that case.

You can also simply exit the program instead of serving:

```golang
out, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "script.sh").Output()
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
if len(out) == 0 {
   log.Fatal("no output was returned from script")
}
```

You can also add more verifications to `out` here if you wish, like if it is a correct URL, using `net/url` package for instance.

Comment: If `string(out)` has trailing whitespace, then OP will want `redirectTo = strings.TrimSpace(string(out))`.

Comment: Yes you may do that, it depends on if you are certain your script will not add trailing spaces, tabs or `\n` for instance

Comment: When I ran both your solutions I got an error "`no new variables on left side of :=`" which was pointing to the second `err :=` I saw a solution saying to remove the colon for the second `err :=` Would that cause any issues if I removed it? Other than that your solution worked exactly as I wanted, once I removed that colon. @BenjaminBarrois

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois im now getting this error when I open the webpage `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS: localhost redirected you too many times.` is there a way to modify the script to only redirect once it has the `out` variable? or just a way to avoid that error

Comment: You are right I replaced the  `:=` by `=`, because `err` variable is already declared (sorry I had not tested my code).

Comment: I added a solution if you want to check that out is empty.